# Handlebars is iterating but not displaying values

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

So I am trying to render an array of objects with handlebars in my node app, and it seems to be picking up the objects since table rows are being added to the DOM, but none of the inner values are displaying for some reason. Also, I only have 4 results but there are 6 rows. I tried many different tweaks after going through documentation and similar questions, to no avail.

Here is the html

```
<a href="#" id="catalog" class="btn-big-green">Course Catalog</a>
    <table class="jsonTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="year">Year</th>
          <th id="term">Term</th>
          <th id="code">Code</th>
          <th id="title">Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {{#each this}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{year}}</td>
          <td>{{term}}</td>
          <td>{{code}}</td>
          <td>{{title}}</td>
        </tr>
          {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

main.js

```
$(".jsonTable").hide();

  $("#catalog").on("click", function(){
    console.log('catalog button clicked');
    $.get('/catalog', function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $("#catalog").hide();
      $(".jsonTable").show();
    });
  });
});
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjn1j.png)

[DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOGjI.png)

Comment: Refer this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977562/jquery-ajax-handlebars-clear-table-then-repopulate

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. His question didn't help me much. From what I can tell, it looks like he's just having js go and compile a separate template and append it with jQuery. I'm already retrieving all the json in my page and rendering the table, but the actual text is not appearing and I'm not sure why.